# Is there a standard way to swap a query from an ID to a different column like 'name'?

Tags: php, mysql

Instead of my queries being something like /search.php?cat=2, I'd like it instead to be /search.php?cat=SomeName.

I just started learning PHP and MYSQL and of course feel like there's lots of standard practices I'm unaware of. I'm just getting the hang of things (you may disagree ;) and put together a function that swaps name's for ID's, which is working.

Is there a more standard way of doing this?

Working code:

```
function swap_name_for_id($name, $search) {
        global $connection;
        if ($search == 'category') {
            $query = "SELECT categories.id, categories.name
                FROM categories 
                WHERE categories.name = '{$name}'";
        }
        $swap_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($swap_set);
        while ($swap = mysqli_fetch_array($swap_set)) {
            $search_id = $swap["id"];
        }
        return $search_id;
    }
function get_parts_for_category($category_name) {
        $category_id = swap_name_for_id($category_name,     'category');
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT parts.id, parts.name, parts.    part_category
                FROM parts 
                WHERE part_category = {$category_id}
                ORDER BY name ASC";
        $part_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        confirm_query($part_set);
        return $part_set;
    }
```

Comment: Anytime you take user provided input and bake it into some SQL, ALWAYS make sure the escape the user provided values to avoid a type of attack known as SQL Injection

Comment: You're right, it's on my list. I just haven't gotten to the point of learning the ins and outs of security yet. Even though they're choosing a Category from a drop-down in this instance, I assume it's still an issue because the user could still type whatever they want into the address bar for the query string?

Comment: Yes, a good approach is to use a database library with query utility methods that always escape user provided values. The php framework codeigniter comes with such a class.

Comment: Remember that ANY values taken from a user (even drop downs, as anybody that wants to can easily modify them and then send the new values) is a security risk. You don't necessarily need to use a library, the built in escape functions should do the trick (mysqli_real_escape_string() I believe it's called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally as far as I know you just do a second query like you do, although they are usually combined into one query, like this:

```
function get_parts_for_category($category_name) {
    global $connection;
    $query = "SELECT parts.id, parts.name, parts.part_category
            FROM parts 
            WHERE part_category = (SELECT categories.id FROM categories WHERE categories.name = '{$category_name}')
            ORDER BY name ASC";
    $part_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    confirm_query($part_set);
    return $part_set;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I didn't remember you could do another query inside. However, copy/pasting that didn't work. I tried changing it to
    WHERE part_category = (SELECT categories.id, categories.name FROM categories WHERE categories.name = '{$category_name}')
But now I'm getting "Database query failed. Operand should contain 1 column(s)"

Comment: My bad, the inner `where` clause in my answer was wrong, you need to only select the `categories.id` field as that's what it uses in the outside query's `where` clause. Check my answer now.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much! I'm still giving myself an attaboy for my crazy function solution though ;)

Comment: When it comes to programming there are usually a ton of solutions that will work for a given problem, and there isn't always a best one. Remember to aim for briefness, but ALWAYS keep things readable, no matter how short you an make something if it's not readable it's not worth it.